# Get MethodInfo object from token, or get Type object from token

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.0, system.reflection

I am trying to use the debugger APIs(ICorDebug etc ) to debug a .net application. The  `IMetadataImport` always returns a token for anything. Be it a Type or a Method. But I want to do reflection on those items. So I need to get the `Type` object or the `MethodInfo` object from those tokens. Is there any way I can do this.

Also is there any way I can acquire the Type objects in a debugee other than how I am doing currently? Here is how I am doing currently.
from the `ICorDebugManagedCallback.LoadModule` callback, I get the `ICorDebugModule` object and call `GetMetaDataInterface` to get the `IMetadataImport` object. But everything inside IMetadataImport deals with tokens. Is there any other way I can get Type and MethodInfo objects on the debugee.

Comment: Why you do not sign answer as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can load the module, you can use [*Module.ResolveType*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1feech8s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [*Module.ResolveMethod*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k16h33dz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load the tokens.